# I need to pause the code from executing until the user clicks on the webpage 2 times

Tags: javascript

I want to run a for loop but I do not want it to execute all at once.

```
for(var i = 0; i < array1.length;i++){
    var tempArray[];
    var tempArrayRevised = [];
confirm("Click the page twice!");
    //This is where I want the code to pause until the webpage has been clicked on twice

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        tempArrayRevised.push(tempArray[i+1]);
    }
    array2.push(tempArrayRevised);
    //unhighlight position
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide more context. Why are you doing this? Why not just listen for 2 click events and then loop when they have occured?

Comment: And if the goal is to loop through an array in 2 parts, then use Array.protototype.slice() to create the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
runned=false;
window.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
if(runned==true){
    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
tempArrayRevised.push(tempArray[i+1]); } 
array2.push(tempArrayRevised);}}

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length;i++){
var  tempArray[]; 
var tempArrayRevised = [];
confirm("Click the page twice!");
runned=true;
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var tempArray[];
    var tempArrayRevised = [];
    var pageClickCount = 0;

    if (confirm("Click the page twice!")) {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
            pageClickCount += 1;
            execRest();
        });
        document.body.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
            pageClickCount += 2;
            execRest();
        });
    }

    function execRest() {
        if (pageClickCount >= 2) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                tempArrayRevised.push(tempArray[i + 1]);
            }
            array2.push(tempArrayRevised);
            //unhighlight position
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are redeclaring your arrays, click count and execRest function per loop. Just...no.

Comment: I need them to be reset each time it loops around. I just really need the program to pop up a confirm asking them to click twice and wait till they click twice before the rest of it loops through

Comment: Even if you need the variables to "reset" each time (in which case, you probably don't need a loop at all) you wouldn't redeclare them as seen in this example and you certainly wouldn't redeclare a function within a loop.

Comment: @VictoriaMiller Did you see my answer? It answers your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're doing this but based on the information provided, here are a few lines of code that:

1. Starts to loop through 'thingArray' and increment 'loopCount' var
2. When 'loopCount' is equal to 2, we break out of the loop and bind the click event
3. When the click event has fired twice, we call the 'resume' function which loops through the remaining items.

The variable loopCount is not necessary but I've put it there so that you can refer to it for other logic that occurs during this process you're creating. You could obviously just use the local i var within the loop for simple increment checking.

The 'break' statement is the key component here and the code is meant to demonstrate that primarily.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jbird/2zza826j/

In the browser console you will see a message for each click event and then finally, when the loop has finished in the 'resume' function, you will see the integer 4 which is the length of the array obviously.

Oh, and I wouldn't suggest binding user initiated events directly on the window.

```
var clickTarget = document.querySelectorAll('.click-target')[0],
    loopCount = 0,
    clickCount = 0,
    thingArray = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4'],
    thingDoneArray =  [];

function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < thingArray.length; i++) {
        loopCount += 1;

        thingDoneArray.push(thingArray[i])

        if(loopCount == 2) {
            // Bind your click event
            clickTarget.addEventListener('click', onClick);

            // Alert the user
            alert('Click the page twice...for some reason.');

            // Break out of the loop (this is the important part)
            break;
        }
    }
}

function resume() {
    for(var i = 0; i < thingArray.length - thingDoneArray.length; i++) {
        loopCount += 1;
    }

    console.log(loopCount);
}

function onClick(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

    clickCount += 1;

    console.log('1 click event happened.');

    if(clickCount == 2) {
      clickTarget.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
      resume();
    }
}

start();
```